# smart caret in python on underscores in textmate

Tags: python, textmate

Consider the following line of code in eclipse java editor.

```
int myFirstVar = 0;
```

I can use cmd + arrow keys to position my cursor at the beginning of the line, end of line and also at the characters m, F, V, =, 0. I did a bit of searching and found that this is possible in eclipse using smart caret settings. Is this possible in textmate for python code. I generally use underscores in my variable names in python. The smart caret could position the cursor at whitespaces and underscores for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to navigate via arrow keys and modifiers, although some might conflict with the latest OS X Spaces switching.

- Alt+arrow jumps through "word-like" characters, meaning it'll skip over all letters, numbers, and underscores, but will stop for spaces, punctuation, etc.
- Ctrl+arrow jumps through smart detection of naming schemes.  It'll stop at various points on `MyVarName` and `my_var_name`.  This is probably what you want.

Using these in combination helps you navigate very precisely, without making one key combination try to do everything.

If doing Ctrl+arrow makes your desktop flip to a different fullscreen view, visit your System Preferences for `Keyboard`, go to the `Shortcuts` tab, and view the `Mission Control` section from the left sidebar.  You'll see a grouping at the bottom of the list which assigns keyboard hotkeys to moving spaces.  You can disable or reassign these as you see fit, to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't upvote it because it requires a min reputation. Btw is there a way I can override this behavior. ie. use alt + arrow key instead of ctrl + arrow key

Comment: @rky You have some options--you can either try to configure a `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` (http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/), or Record a macro (Edit > Macros) and save it as a bundle item with a new key bound to it.  The macro is readable and can probably be converted to a hard KeyBindings.dict entry if you use the names TextMate gives to those actions (`moveSubWordRight`, `moveSubWordLeft` for smart cursor movement)